# Postgresql function - Parse the input json, build and return json object

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.4

I need to write one function which get json as input parameter and returns json.

Input json:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"}]
```

Output json:

```
{  "success":[{"id":1,"name":"a"}],"failed":[{"id":2,"name":"b"}]}
```

LOOP the input array, process (some logic) and return the response with success and failed array items.

Comment: But `{id:1}` is not valid json, would have to be `{"id":1}`

Answer (score 1):

```
select  json_build_object(
            'success', json_agg(col1) filter (where col1->>'name' <> 'a'),
            'failure', json_agg(col1)  filter (where col1->>'name' = 'a'))
from    json_array_elements('[{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"}]'::json) as t(col1)
```

Prints:

```
{"success" : [{"id":2,"name":"b"}], "failure" : [{"id":1,"name":"a"}]}
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/12845/0)

Comment: I want to process the input array (loop) and push the failed items into failed array in return json object. need to add new attribute (reason) with failed items like below.

{"success":[{"id":2,"name":"b"}] "failed":[{"id":1,"name":"a","reason":"Conflict"}]}

Answer (score 0):

```
    console.clear();
    var jsonObj = '[{"id":1,"name":"a"},{"id":2,"name":"b"}]';

    function formatJson(input) {

        let arr = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
        //     console.log(arr);
        let retJson = {
            "success": [],
            "failure": []
        };

        arr.forEach((item) => {

            if (true) { // some condition to put json data in success object. Here i am making it always true for implementation purpose
                retJson.success.push(item);

            } else {
                //failure logic
            }

        });

        return retJson;

    }
    var formattedJSONOutput = formatJson(jsonObj);
    console.log(formattedJSONOutput);
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/faran4engg/vzbooahL/3/)

Comment: Its not javascript function. Postgresql function